# COALESCE (DATEPART) Not validating

Tags: sql

I'm in the process of validating the following query where my expected result is a row with a revenue value of 0 for any week where there is no revenue to SUM. What I'm getting is only one 0 revenue record where I know there are many.  Can someone take a look at my code and see if there is anything obvious I screwed up?

```
SELECT dbo.LMCustomer.Name, 
       SUM(dbo.LMDelivery.LdryCensChrg + dbo.LMDelivery.LdryWghtChrg + dbo.LMDelivery.LdryPiecChrg - dbo.LMDelivery.RetnWghtCred - dbo.LMDelivery.RetnPiecCred - dbo.LMDelivery.VrncChrg + dbo.LMDelivery.LdryDelvChrg +
                          dbo.LMDelivery.PrchChrg + dbo.LMDelivery.LdryPcntChrg + dbo.LMDelivery.AuxpChrg01 + dbo.LMDelivery.AuxpChrg02 + dbo.LMDelivery.AuxpChrg03 + dbo.LMDelivery.AuxpChrg04 + dbo.LMDelivery.AuxpChrg05 + dbo.LMDelivery.AuxpChrg06
                          + dbo.LMDelivery.AuxpChrg07 + dbo.LMDelivery.AuxpChrg08 + dbo.LMDelivery.AuxpChrg09 + dbo.LMDelivery.AuxpChrg10 + dbo.LMDelivery.AuxpChrg11 + dbo.LMDelivery.AuxpChrg12 - dbo.LMDelivery.AuxpCred01 - dbo.LMDelivery.AuxpCred02
                          - dbo.LMDelivery.AuxpCred03 - dbo.LMDelivery.AuxpCred04 - dbo.LMDelivery.AuxpCred05 - dbo.LMDelivery.AuxpCred06 - dbo.LMDelivery.AuxpCred07 - dbo.LMDelivery.AuxpCred08 - dbo.LMDelivery.AuxpCred09 - dbo.LMDelivery.AuxpCred10
                          - dbo.LMDelivery.AuxpCred11 - dbo.LMDelivery.AuxpCred12 + dbo.LMDelivery.AuxmChrg01 + dbo.LMDelivery.AuxmChrg02 + dbo.LMDelivery.AuxmChrg03 + dbo.LMDelivery.AuxmChrg04 + dbo.LMDelivery.AuxmChrg05 + dbo.LMDelivery.AuxmChrg06
                          + dbo.LMDelivery.AuxmChrg07 + dbo.LMDelivery.AuxmChrg08 - dbo.LMDelivery.AuxmCred01 - dbo.LMDelivery.AuxmCred02 - dbo.LMDelivery.AuxmCred03 - dbo.LMDelivery.AuxmCred04 - dbo.LMDelivery.AuxmCred05 - dbo.LMDelivery.AuxmCred06
                          - dbo.LMDelivery.AuxmCred07 - dbo.LMDelivery.AuxmCred08) AS Revenue
FROM dbo.LMDelivery INNER JOIN
                         dbo.LMCustomer ON dbo.LMDelivery.ShipCustRcID = dbo.LMCustomer.RcID INNER JOIN
                         dbo.LMContract ON dbo.LMDelivery.ContRcID = dbo.LMContract.RcID
WHERE        (dbo.LMDelivery.UsefCanc = 0) AND (dbo.LMContract.StrtDate >= '2018-01-01') AND (dbo.LMDelivery.LdryDelvDate >= '2018-01-01')
GROUP BY dbo.LMCustomer.RcID, dbo.LMCustomer.Name, COALESCE (DATEPART(week, dbo.LMDelivery.LdryDelvDate), 0)
```

Comment: Tell us WHY there should be many records. One record per what? It sounds like your not-to-be-aggregated columns (sort of the result key) got put by you into the group by clause.

Comment: Provide sample data please

Comment: There should be a record for each week (Monday - Sunday), for each customer from 2018-01-01 forward.

Comment: can you show us the data you get without sum and group by, Just a plain select of the fields you are grouping by and date fields as well. also some of the fields from sum would be good to look at .

Comment: Here's some sample data... [link](https://1drv.ms/f/s!AvLK0hZDf0Y7fatEyr5r7ORbx0s)

Comment: You have to add 49 columns together to get Revenue? That's a suspect data model.

Comment: @EricBrandt I don't know much to anything about data models... any resources you can share?

Answer (score 0):

Your query is limited to only show weeks where there is a delivery (and thus, presumably, revenue) by the use of the `LMDelivery` table in the FROM clause.

If you wished to see a list of all customers, all weeks, and whatever delivery information is necessary, then you're going to need to start with a list of all customers and all weeks.

Assuming SQL Server, you could use a CTE to come up with a list of the weeks that have been in the year so far, connect that with your customer list, then seek out any relevant deliveries and their associated contracts.  Something like the following:

```
;WITH 
e1(n) AS
    (
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
    ), -- 10
e2(n) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY e1.n) AS n FROM e1 CROSS JOIN e1 AS b), -- 10*10
num(WeekOfYear) AS 
    (
    SELECT  
        n - 1
    FROM e2
    WHERE n <= DATEPART(WEEK, GETDATE()) + 1
    )



SELECT dbo.LMCustomer.Name, 
       SUM(dbo.LMDelivery.LdryCensChrg + dbo.LMDelivery.LdryWghtChrg + dbo.LMDelivery.LdryPiecChrg - dbo.LMDelivery.RetnWghtCred - dbo.LMDelivery.RetnPiecCred - dbo.LMDelivery.VrncChrg + dbo.LMDelivery.LdryDelvChrg +
                          dbo.LMDelivery.PrchChrg + dbo.LMDelivery.LdryPcntChrg + dbo.LMDelivery.AuxpChrg01 + dbo.LMDelivery.AuxpChrg02 + dbo.LMDelivery.AuxpChrg03 + dbo.LMDelivery.AuxpChrg04 + dbo.LMDelivery.AuxpChrg05 + dbo.LMDelivery.AuxpChrg06
                          + dbo.LMDelivery.AuxpChrg07 + dbo.LMDelivery.AuxpChrg08 + dbo.LMDelivery.AuxpChrg09 + dbo.LMDelivery.AuxpChrg10 + dbo.LMDelivery.AuxpChrg11 + dbo.LMDelivery.AuxpChrg12 - dbo.LMDelivery.AuxpCred01 - dbo.LMDelivery.AuxpCred02
                          - dbo.LMDelivery.AuxpCred03 - dbo.LMDelivery.AuxpCred04 - dbo.LMDelivery.AuxpCred05 - dbo.LMDelivery.AuxpCred06 - dbo.LMDelivery.AuxpCred07 - dbo.LMDelivery.AuxpCred08 - dbo.LMDelivery.AuxpCred09 - dbo.LMDelivery.AuxpCred10
                          - dbo.LMDelivery.AuxpCred11 - dbo.LMDelivery.AuxpCred12 + dbo.LMDelivery.AuxmChrg01 + dbo.LMDelivery.AuxmChrg02 + dbo.LMDelivery.AuxmChrg03 + dbo.LMDelivery.AuxmChrg04 + dbo.LMDelivery.AuxmChrg05 + dbo.LMDelivery.AuxmChrg06
                          + dbo.LMDelivery.AuxmChrg07 + dbo.LMDelivery.AuxmChrg08 - dbo.LMDelivery.AuxmCred01 - dbo.LMDelivery.AuxmCred02 - dbo.LMDelivery.AuxmCred03 - dbo.LMDelivery.AuxmCred04 - dbo.LMDelivery.AuxmCred05 - dbo.LMDelivery.AuxmCred06
                          - dbo.LMDelivery.AuxmCred07 - dbo.LMDelivery.AuxmCred08) AS Revenue
FROM 
    dbo.LMCustomer INNER JOIN 
    num ON 1=1 LEFT JOIN 
    dbo.LMDelivery ON dbo.LMDelivery.ShipCustRcID = dbo.LMCustomer.RcID LEFT JOIN
    dbo.LMContract ON dbo.LMDelivery.ContRcID = dbo.LMContract.RcID
WHERE        LMDelivery.ShipCustRcID IS NULL OR (
    (dbo.LMDelivery.UsefCanc = 0) AND (dbo.LMContract.StrtDate >= '2018-01-01') AND (dbo.LMDelivery.LdryDelvDate >= '2018-01-01')
    AND COALESCE (DATEPART(week, LMDelivery.LdryDelvDate), 0) =  num.WeekOfYear
    )
GROUP BY dbo.LMCustomer.RcID, dbo.LMCustomer.NAME, num.WeekOfYear
```